# Unsupported SSH connection when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, ssh, pyinstaller, fs, paramiko

I am connecting via SSH using fs.sshfs like this,

```
  my_fs = fs.open_fs(u'ssh://myuser:mypassword@my.server.com:22/share/directory/')
```

It is working fine when I run the script using PyCharm. However, when I create my EXE using PyInstaller and I run the executable I get this error:

```
fs.opener.errors.UnsupportedProtocol: protocol 'ssh' is not supported
```

I think that the PyInstaller doesn't include fs.sshfs and I have tried also to run PyInstaller with the following options:

```
--nowindow --hidden-import=fs.sshfs
```

The error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug from PyInstaller. You can find the fix here:
https://github.com/althonos/fs.sshfs/issues/42